# C# interview questions approaches in entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

In my recent interview, my interviewer we asked about approaches in entity Framework I told them code first and table first. Is there any approaches pending.

Comment: Google will help you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use three type of entity framework approach as per project requirement.

Database First:

1. An existing database can be used
2. Code can be auto-generated.
3. Extensible using partial classes/ T4 templates
4. The developer can update the database manually
5. There is a very good designer, which sync with the underlining database

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/database-first-with-entity-framework.aspx

Code First:

1. There is full control of the model from the Code; no EDMX/designer
2. No manual intervention to DB is required
3. The database is used for data only

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx

Model First:

1. Good support with EDMX designer
2. We can visually create the database model
3. EF generates the Code and database script
4. Extensible through partial classes